# Developer tools: Monitor a wordpress/website's requested php/html files - hunting which content.php is used

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

Hello I have been messing around with the website I am developing using wordpress as cms.

and Just when I have finished everything, all the featured images from my home/index were gone.

I did some experimenting and found out that Wordpress isn't using simply just content.php.
I tested it by making obvious changes to it. I even tried renaming it (that would make all contents disappear) but nothing happened.

Now I just want to know which files are included by thi line:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
```

I've tried echoing the value of get_post_format(); but it returns nothing.

is there a program to trace which php file it calls?
or is there a way to echo out the name of the php file it used?
or should I force wordpress to use the content.php I made changes?
if yes, how?

I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of hacky, but might be able to get the job done.

```
$filesBefore = get_included_files();

//after get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

$files = array_diff($fileBefore, get_included_files());

echo '<pre>' . $files . '</pre>';
```

This should show you the difference between the files that had been included before the line you mentioned and then afterwards.

Comment: Sir thank you for taking the time to answer my question.
I understand what your idea is. However, it returns this error:
.
`Warning: array_diff() [<a href='function.array-diff'>function.array-diff</a>]: Argument #1 is not an array in C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\twentyeleven\index.php on line 44`

Comment: Never mind..
I echoed out all values with for each
then made a second array containing the new list of incuded files and compared it manually. :)
I found the file now.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

`<?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>` calls content.php of your wordpress theme